# How can i be sure my contracted developer will create scalable work on my Wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress

A few months ago, I hired a developer to make some changes to my small Wordpress/Woocommerce website. The changes looked good but the next time I updated the theme things went wrong. Most changes seems to vanish and things stopped working. I couldn't contact the developer again. In many ways, it was my fault, as I went for someone cheap as I had very little budget. It's tempting when you're broke to go cheap!.

I eventually reverted to backup.

Now I want to try again and make some more changes to woocommerce templates. Nothing major, just removing text and some alignment changes.

My question is what should a developer do to make these changes more permanent? Is it a child theme? Is it more complex? WHat questions should I ask to make sure they don't just directly edit the code in a non-permanent way like last time?

Thanks so much for your help
JP

Comment: The way you describe it it sounds as if they altered theme files/templates, which they shouldn't do, since these changes will be lost as soon as the theme is updated. A way to prevent this is to create a *child theme* which will not be changed even if the main theme (on which the child theme is based) is updated.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Child theme is the way I will go

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use a WordPress child theme.
You can also read  [this](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-update-a-wordpress-theme-without-losing-customization/) article, so that you can update the theme safely.

You can also use a Code Snippet plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/